# scala coursera week 6 assignment method compile error

Tags: scala

I am doing scala course on coursera. I am going through week 6 assignment. I am stuck with combinations function.

Here are the description of the problem:

```
type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]
/**
   * Returns the list of all subsets of the occurrence list.
   *  This includes the occurrence itself, i.e. `List(('k', 1), ('o', 1))`
   *  is a subset of `List(('k', 1), ('o', 1))`.
   *  It also include the empty subset `List()`.
   *
   *  Example: the subsets of the occurrence list `List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))` are:
   *
   *    List(
   *      List(),
   *      List(('a', 1)),
   *      List(('a', 2)),
   *      List(('b', 1)),
   *      List(('a', 1), ('b', 1)),
   *      List(('a', 2), ('b', 1)),
   *      List(('b', 2)),
   *      List(('a', 1), ('b', 2)),
   *      List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))
   *    )
   *
   *  Note that the order of the occurrence list subsets does not matter -- the subsets
   *  in the example above could have been displayed in some other order.
   */

  def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] =???
```

Here is my solution based on what I could understand the logic:

```
def combinations(occurences: Occurrences) : List[Occurrences] = {

  def restTuplesCombination(occ: Occurrences, xs: List[Occurrences]): List[Occurrences] = occ match {
    case Nil=> xs :+ Nil
    case head :: rest => {
      for(
        entry <- headTupleCombination(head)
        combination <- restTuplesCombination(rest, xs) // getting error here
      ) yield if(entry._2 == 0)
        combination
      else
        entry :: combination
      // case close
    }
  }

  def headTupleCombination(tuple: (Char, Int) ):List[( Char, Int)] = {
    if(tuple._2 < 0)
      Nil
    else
      tuple :: headTupleCombination( (tuple._1, tuple._2 -1))
  }

  restTuplesCombination(occurences, Nil)
}
```

The method is quite long but it looks readable to me. I am getting at statement: **combination <- restTuplesCombination(rest, xs)**

I am not able to understand what is breaking the code here. both the expressions in for loop return two collections and I am using yield to create combinations of elements.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SteffenSchmitz's answer is correct, but here's some clarification on the issue:

Round braces `()` and curly braces `{}` are interpreted slightly differently in Scala. Anything specified between round braces that isn't delimited by commas or semicolons is considered to be *a single expression*. In contrast, anything specified between curly braces is treated as *one expression per line* by default.<sup>†</sup>

In other words, this portion of your code:

```
  for(
    entry <- headTupleCombination(head)
    combination <- restTuplesCombination(rest, xs)
  )
```

is parsed the same as if you'd written it like this:

```
  for(entry <- headTupleCombination(head) combination <- restTuplesCombination(rest, xs)) // all on one line
```

You can fix the problem by adding a semicolon, which explicitly tells the parser that you're writing two separate expressions:

```
  for(
    entry <- headTupleCombination(head); // added semicolon here
    combination <- restTuplesCombination(rest, xs)
  )
```

Or, as suggested by SteffenSchmitz, you can just switch the round braces to curly braces, which tells the parser to expect one expression per line:

```
  for {
    entry <- headTupleCombination(head)
    combination <- restTuplesCombination(rest, xs)
  }
```

Using curly braces for a `for` expression with multiple levels like this is the preferred style.

---

<sup>†</sup> I say "by default" here because there are some cases when the parser will automatically combine two lines into a single expression; e.g., if a line ends with a binary operator, then the next line is assumed to be the right-hand argument to the binary operator. So the following two curly-brace-enclosed expressions are parsed identically:

```
{
  1 +
  2
}

{ 1 + 2 }
```

Comment: Thanks DaoWen. I understand this difference now.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax issue there. If you replace the round brackets around the for assignments with curly braces it compiles:

```
type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]

def combinations(occurences: Occurrences) : List[Occurrences] = {

  def restTuplesCombination(occ: Occurrences, xs: List[Occurrences]): List[Occurrences] = occ match {
    case Nil=> xs :+ Nil
    case head :: rest =>
      for {
        entry <- headTupleCombination(head)
        combination <- restTuplesCombination(rest, xs)
      } yield
        if(entry._2 == 0)
          combination
        else
          entry :: combination
  }

  def headTupleCombination(tuple: (Char, Int) ): List[( Char, Int)] = {
    if(tuple._2 < 0)
      Nil
    else
      tuple :: headTupleCombination( (tuple._1, tuple._2 -1))
  }

  restTuplesCombination(occurences, Nil)
}
```